# Missing faces after adding Boolean modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, screw-modifier

I have a problem applying boolean after screw modifier.

Somehow boolean doesn`t work properly and some faces are missing along the cut.
[image: Rim]

[Img. Missing faces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJcQV.jpg)

[image]

I`ve already checked mesh for duplicate vertices.
Applied scale and other transformation to all objects.
And recalculated normals.

Here is URL to .blend file:
[boolean-bug.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g04ZxpxuscKCKYo32GOmmV1ReqWhPzrN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the faces and edges in the middle before using the screw modifier. Because or else there will be interior faces in the mesh and it messes up the boolean modifier.

[image: face removed]

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! It was the root of the problem.